# Query that Gets Transactions a user can take in SQLServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a tblData and a tblUser.

I only want to display the transactions that the user can take.

The transactions are linked by a DisplayNum, if one of the Transactions in the DisplayNum does not match the TransType in the tblUser then the user cannot take any TransType in that DisplayNum.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify the desired output? Why isn't C3 included and why does `D5 Checkout 10`show 10 and not 9 as value? Does the tblUser include the DisplayNum field too?

Comment: @jpw C3 is not included since the user doesnt take Take In. Omit the last line it should output only the highest for the DisplayNum.

Comment: @jpw D5 is 10 for TransTime since D5 Check Out + D5 No Shoe Trans Times adds to 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final version put together after some chatting:

```
SELECT DISTINCT q2.Id, q3.SubQ, q1.DisplayNum, q1.TransType, q1.TotalTransTime, q1.UserId 
FROM (
    SELECT D.DisplayNum, HighestTransTime.TransType, SUM(D.TransTime) AS TotalTransTime, U.UserId 
    FROM tblData D
    INNER JOIN tblUser U ON D.TransType=U.TransType
    INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT innerQuery.DisplayNum, TransType 
        FROM tblData 
        INNER JOIN 
            (
            SELECT DisplayNum, MAX(TransTime) AS TransTime FROM tblData GROUP BY DisplayNum
            ) innerQuery ON tblData.DisplayNum = innerQuery.DisplayNum AND tblData.TransTime = innerQuery.TransTime
        ) HighestTransTime ON D.DisplayNum=HighestTransTime.DisplayNum 
    WHERE U.UserId = 10 
    AND D.TransType IN (SELECT TransType FROM tblUser WHERE tblUser.UserId = U.UserId)
    AND D.DisplayNum NOT IN (SELECT DisplayNum FROM tblData WHERE TransType NOT IN (SELECT TransType FROM tblUser WHERE tblUser.UserId = U.UserId))
    GROUP BY D.DisplayNum, HighestTransTime.TransType, U.UserId
    ) q1
INNER JOIN (SELECT DisplayNum, MAX(ID) AS ID FROM tblData GROUP BY DisplayNum) q2 ON q1.DisplayNum = q2.DisplayNum
INNER JOIN (SELECT SubQ, ID FROM tblData) q3 ON q2.ID=q3.ID
ORDER BY q2.ID
```

Comment: I am going to test it. Why do you have CASE C.TransType WHEN 'No Show' THEN 'Check Out'. What if is different Trans.

Comment: Almost there. What If I have different Cases for example if its for D5 Process and another D5 Checkout, output being D5 Check Out 14. It could change everytime.

Comment: Where can I add the parameter for the UserID

Comment: Do you have the SQlFiddle?

Comment: I believe I found a bug. When the TransTime are equal it does not add correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33920/discussion-between-apollo-and-jpw)

Answer (score 0):

As far I can understand you could use simple join on `TransType` column.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.tblData INNER JOIN dbo.tblUser ON 
dbo.tblData .TransType = dbo.tblUser .TransType
```

Comment: This answer doesn't fulfill the requirement: `if one of the Transactions in the DisplayNum does not match the TransType in the tblUser then the user cannot take any TransType in that DisplayNum.` Also it doesn't sum the total transtime as per requirement stated.